# $\int\frac{{11}/{10}}{2x+2}dx$ what is wrong

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{\frac{11}{10}}{(2x+2)}dx$$

$$\frac{11}{10}\int \frac{dx}{(2x+2)}$$

$$t=2x+2$$

$$dt=2dx$$

$$dx=\frac{dt}{2}$$

$$\frac{11}{10}\int\frac{1}{t}\frac{dt}{2}$$

$$\frac{11}{20}\int\frac{1}{t}dt$$

$$\frac{11}{20}\ln|t|+C$$

$$\frac{11}{20}\ln|2x+2|+C$$

what is wrong?

Comment: Apart from the notation? :-)

Comment: Yes, It's not that bad.... :( I hope

Comment: Not really... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%2811%2F10%29%2F%282x%2B2%29dx

Comment: The calculation and answer are correct. Note that your answer and Alpha's differ by a constant. This is taken care of by the constant of integration.

Comment: $\ln |2x+2| = \ln|x+1| + \ln|2| $

Comment: I don't understand. ln|2x+2|+C=ln|x+1|+C=ln|200x+200|+C ?

Comment: Different C's. To persuade yourself of the correctness of your answer, differentiate it.

Comment: 2ln|x+1|+c=ln|x+1|+c=200ln|x+1|+c ???

Comment: No @user332048 but
$\ln(2x+2)+c_1=\ln(2)+\ln(x+1)+c_1=\ln(x+1)+\ln(200)+c_2=\ln(200x+200)+c_2$